# Is this a good example of Reactive Extensions? How can I make this better?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;

namespace ReactiveExtensions
    {
    class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var start = Observable.Start(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting some work done");
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    //go call stackoverflow
                    var d = CallStackOverFlow();
                    //send the result for checking to a delegate
                    foreach (var q in d.questions)
                        {
                            var list = (q.tags as JArray).Values().Select(v => v.ToString()).ToList();
                            var result = FindByTag(list);
                            if(result)
                                Console.WriteLine("Quesion title :{0}",q.title);
                        }
                 }
                return "I am done observing";
            });
            Console.WriteLine("Subscribing"); // Make visible when we subscribe
            start.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static readonly Func<List<String>,bool> FindByTag =(x => x.Contains("c#"));

        private static dynamic CallStackOverFlow()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1");
            var request = new RestRequest("/questions/no-answers", Method.POST);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
            dynamic deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
            return deserialised;
        }
     }
  }
```

Please add the tag for ReactiveExtensions , my reputation does not allow me to do that.

Comment: Please describe what it does, what is it's purpose, and what features of Rx does it demonstrate.

Comment: i am not sure exactly what features of Rx it demonstrates. I think i have created a pseudo stream , although i am not doing much work in an async manner . I think i should make the code do the checking while it waits for the next round of results.

Comment: At least start by removing nesting levels. Extract the parts of each for loop to a method. Consider whether parameters should be fields. It will make each part of your logic easier to maintain and read.

Answer (score 3):

possible improvements :

1. make CallStackOverflow asynchronous
2. use Observavle.Timer instead of thread.sleep

Here is what it would look like

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

        Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        .Take(10)
        .Select(() => CallStackOverFlow().ToObservable())
        .Select(d => {
             //send the result for checking to a delegate
               foreach (var q in d.questions)
                   {
                       var list = (q.tags as JArray).Values().Select(v => v.ToString()).ToList();
                       var result = FindByTag(list);
                       if(result)
                           Console.WriteLine("Quesion title :{0}",q.title);
                   }
         })
         .Wait();

       Console.WriteLine("Subscribing"); // Make visible when we subscribe
       start.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
       Console.ReadKey();
   }

   private static readonly Func<List<String>,bool> FindByTag =(x => x.Contains("c#"));

   private static async  Task<dynamic> CallStackOverFlow()
   {
       var client = new RestClient("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1");
       var request = new RestRequest("/questions/no-answers", Method.POST);
       // -- async invocation
       var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request); 
       // or  var response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<TResponse>(client.BeginExecute, client.EndExecute, null);
       var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
       dynamic deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
       return deserialised;
   }
}
```